# FFmpeg concat video and audio out of sync

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, concatenation

Joining multiple files using ffmpeg [concat](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate) seems to result in a mismatch of the timestamps or offsets for the audio. I've tried with several videos and noticed the same problem for h.264 / MP4.

Using `concat` *and encoding* the video seems to work fine. The audio stays in sync as ffmpeg does the full conversion calculations and seems to get everything right.

However, simply concatenating the videos without any transformation or encoding results in a slowly increasing sync issue. Obviously, encoding the videos rather than simply joining them will result in a loss of information/quality so I would rather find a way around this problem.

I've [tried several flags](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) to sort out this problem that appears to be based on the timestamps. None of these seem to correct the problem though.

```
ffmpeg -f concat -fflags +genpts -async 1 -i segments.txt test.mov
ffmpeg -auto_convert 1 -f concat -fflags +genpts -async 1 -i segments.txt -c copy test2.mov
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -c copy -fflags +genpts test3.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -fflags +genpts -async 1 -i segments.txt -copyts test4.mov
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -copyts test5.mov
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -copyts -c copy test6.mov
ffmpeg -f concat -fflags +genpts -i segments.txt -copyts -c copy test7.mov
```

*Note: all other questions that I could find on SO seem to "fix" the problem by simply encoding the videos over again. Not a good solution.*

### Update

I realized the concat wasn't the problem. The original set of clips had mis-matched timestamps. Somehow concat + encoding fixed the issue, but I don't want to re-encode the videos and loose quality each time.

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:02.750 -i input.MOV -c copy -t 00:00:05.880 output.MOV
```

Which resulted in the following data

```
ffprobe -v quiet -show_entries stream=start_time,duration output.MOV

start_time=-0.247500
duration=6.131125
start_time=-0.257333
duration=6.155333
```

Since then I've tried to use `-to`m and `-t` in different places along with `-af apad -c:v copy` and I've still failed to get the duration to be the same.

#### [Here is the full ffprobe output](https://gist.github.com/Xeoncross/ec27c8a7f12c137a85fd)

#### [Here is the original (red) vs the segment (green)](https://www.diffchecker.com/kwxdlyfy)

#### Detailed Sample Files

I recorded a sample video, added the commands to chop it up, then concat it. http://davidpennington.me/share/audio_sync_test_video.zip

Comment: Audio may have to be re-encoded but not [video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397034/ffmpeg-concatenate-videos-with-audio-not-synched/35397602#35397602). You can use `-video_track_timescale` to change video timebase of MOV/MP4s without re-encoding. If you paste details of input files, that will be helpful.

Comment: I think it might be related to this [ffmpeg ticket for mp4/aac](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/3859)

Comment: [This comment about keyframes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18449609/99923) might be part of the problem with the audio sync issues.

Comment: sboisse suggests using [ffprobe to find the nearest keyframes, then clip at that point](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14013439/99923).

Answer (score 30):

This two step process should work

**Step 1**  Pad out the audio in each segment

```
ffmpeg -i segment1.mov -af apad -c:v copy <audio encoding params> -shortest -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts padded1.mov
```

Or

Generate segments with synced streams

```
ffmpeg -y -ss 00:00:02.750 -i input.MOV -c copy -t 00:00:05.880 -avoid_negative_ts make_zero -fflags +genpts segment.MOV
```

**Step 2** Concat

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i segments.txt -c copy test.mov
```

where `segments.txt` consists of the names of the padded files.

Comment: What does "padding the audio" do? How does it fix the timestamps?

Comment: The audio in some or all of the segments is not equal to the video length. So the audio joints aren't at the same time as the video joints hence the async. The first step pads the audio i.e. adds indefinite period of silence at the end of each segment, but the shortest stops the operation when the video stream ends thus rendering both audio and video to be the same length (as much as possible).

Comment: I tried `-af apad -c:v copy <audio encoding params> -shortest` but it still didn't fix the video duration.

Comment: Are these segments from the same file?

Comment: Yes, the segments are from the same original source file.

Comment: I don't know the codecs of the streams in the file but generally the durations will not match, since both streams are quantized i.e. for a 25 fps video, duration will be multiples of 0.04s, and for AAC audio @ 48 kHz, multiples of 0.0213s. I doubt that's the problem here. Post a ffprobe readout for the whole input and one of the segments you made (before my `apad` suggestion)

Comment: Mulvya, I updated the post with the full ffprobe output. Each segment is the same exact codecs.

Comment: Your segments have negative PTS because ffmpeg is cutting segments at the keyframe before your split point but is assigning PTS 0 to your split point so frames before have negative PTS. So my edited command remedies that. However, there's a hitch. The amount of audio before the split point is not equal to the video before, so there will still be some silence at the joints. sboisse's method may be the safest.

Comment: Unfortunately the audio pad still doesn't result in a sync. I even parsed the ffprobe for the closes keyframes to when I'm splitting the segments out and then added the pad above, still gets out of sync. I'm really wondering what else I can do. Just a couple clips into the combined concat video and the disconnect between video and audio is already 1/6th a second.

Comment: Can you share enough files for me to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I recorded a sample video, added the commands to chop it up, then concat it. http://davidpennington.me/share/audio_sync_test_video.zip I'll be happy to add another 200 point bounty if you can solve this.

Comment: Will look into it. Only saw the above comment today.

Comment: I just scanned the instructions.txt: the concat command is re-encoding the file. Was that meant?

Comment: How much out of sync were you getting with your original method?

Comment: I was trying both re-encoding and straight `-c copy` both causing sync issues. I'm not sure exactly how much out of sync the resulting files were after concat, but it's pretty noticeable just a couple seconds into the video.

Comment: So, like a half a second out of sync (or more)?

Comment: See my non-transcoded concat : http://www.datafilehost.com/d/2bcbf726. Looks in sync to me. Going by the text file, looks like you adapted my step 1 command to your segment generating command instead of feeding it the *generated* segment. See edited answer for a step 1 command to use as a segment-generating step.

Comment: I had to make it a three-step process to sync the audio. First I cut the segment, then I padded it like you show, then I combined them all with concat and it seems to stay in sync. Thank you so much!

Comment: Why? I was able to achieve a in-sync concat by using the new command I posted. Did you see my uploaded video?

Comment: Yes, simply doing the slice + concat worked for that small video. I tried it for a longer video and noticed a very slight sync issue after about 1 minute of video. I checked with ffprobe and all I saw was `.009` offset start time for the video stream. I padded the movie (didn't seem to change much if anything from looking at the wavelengh) but the video synced better even after 1 minute of video and the padded video segments had a new offset of something like `0.042`. I think part of the problem is the player, OS platform, and file types that are also resulting in slightly different outputs.

Comment: Mulvya, regarding your comment above, can you explain how 48Khz = 0.0213s?  Wouldn't 48khz = 1/48000 = 0.0000208333s, therefore being fine enough so that ffmpeg can (start and) end the audio stream almost exactly when the video stream (starts and) ends?

Comment: 1024 samples per AAC audio frame & 48000 Hz = 48000 / 1024 = 46.875 frames/sec. So 1 frame = 0.0213 s.

Comment: @Mulvya, hi, sir, i have tried your solution but in my case it didn't work, can you please have a look at the below so question? please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860443/ffmpeg-f-concat-video-audio-sycn-issue

Comment: @Gyan I am having a similar issue with mp4 files. Unfortunately, when I try with your step1, the -avoid_negative_ts make_zero gives me a incorrect codec parameters error. I've tried searching around to see what could be causing this but not much luck. If I replace the make_zero with a 1, it appears to actually go through but I have no idea what this is doing.

Comment: @RichardThomas open a new Q showing your *full* command and log.

Comment: none of the suggestions here worked for me but then i found that the audio sampling rate was different between the files and once i make all the same concat worked perfectly and i had no audio issues.

Answer (score 12):

I encountered a similar problem and found a solution that worked, at least for me.  In my case, I was also concatenating files, and found audio/video sync problems with iOs, but not with Windows (e.g., VLC media player showed no synchronization problems using the same mp4 file).  The symptom for iOs playing this concatenated mp4 was initially good synchronization followed by an increasing loss of synchronization as the movie played, with audio going faster than video. Interestingly, the sync could be restored temporarily by advancing the movie progress slider to any point in the movie, but then the sync would be lost again as the movie continued to play in iOs. By playing the same movie simultaneously in both iOs and Windows VLC, and initially synchronized with each other as well as I could, by observing the evolution of the "echo" between them, I concluded that the iOs audio was going too fast (assuming the Windows player is correct).

For me, the solution was to add the audio filter option `-af aresample=async=1000` to the ffmpeg command, which I found as an example in the ffmpeg online documentation and used verbatim.  I don't know if this setting is optimal, but the result was a mp4 with audio and video remaining synchronized when played by both iOs and VLC.  This ffmpeg option yielded proper iOs synchronization both during concatenation and afterwards when re-encoding the already concatenated file.

Comment: It's the only solution that worked for me. It requires to reencode the audio tho (error: `Filtergraph 'aresample=async=1000' was defined for audio output stream 0:1 but codec copy was selected. Filtering and streamcopy cannot be used together`) so I had to change the flag `-c copy` to `-c:v copy`.

Comment: I use this argument with the concat filter and it works. And I was like _But why?_

Comment: This solves the issue of async indeed, besides is a way to sync video on top of audio? it may require re-encoding of video track but thats okay with me.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `filter_complex` to concat different options in one go

```
ffmpeg -i input1.mp4 -i input2.webm \
-filter_complex "[0:v:0] [0:a:0] [1:v:0] [1:a:0] concat=n=2:v=1:a=1 [v] [a]" \
-map "[v]" -map "[a]" <encoding options> output.mkv
```

Comment: Your command users a filter, and therefore will re-encode, but Xeoncross wants to avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

I have been struggling with this one for quite some time as well. Particularly when working with Panasonic AVCHD-generated MTS files. My current solution is to concatenate them on the OS level not ffmpeg. I do this on windows and it looks something like this:

```
COPY /b input_1.mts + input_2.mts + input_3.mts output.mts
```

On linux it should be something like:

```
$ cat input_1.mts input_2.mts input_3.mts > output.mts
```

You can look up documentation for the [windows](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/71161) and [linux](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucat.htm) binary concatenation.

This method of concatenation as apposed to transcoding is the way to go if the original format will work for you. This method practically uses no CPU processing and preserves the original quality. A win-win when dealing with bulk media of high quality.

Comment: I would think this would fail with formats that have meta-data as the first X bytes of the file. Maybe not with all the safeguards built into media handling (like reading until the end of file regardless of what the stream data says?)

Comment: This is a valid concern and should be taken into consideration when concatenating files on a binary level.

Comment: TS is a streaming container. This won't work with MP4 or MOVs..etc

Answer (score 1):

If the input videos have the same video format, audio format, dimensions, etc., you can use `mkvmerge` from mkvtoolnix to concatenate the videos without re-encoding:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv file1.mkv + file2.mkv + file3.mkv
```

`mkvmerge` also accepts input files with an MP4 container, but the output file will have an MKV container even if you try to specify the filename extension of the output file as `.mp4`. You can change the container with `ffmpeg`:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv file1.mp4 + file2.mp4 + file3.mp4
ffmpeg -i output.mkv -c copy output.mp4
```

I needed to concatenate videos from different sources that had been encoded with different settings, so I first used a command like this to resize and re-encode the input videos:

`for f in *.mp4;do w=1280;h=720;ffmpeg -i $f -filter:v "scale=iw*min($w/iw\,$h/ih):ih*min($w/iw\,$h/ih),pad=$w:$h:($w-iw*min($w/iw\,$h/ih))/2:($h-ih*min($w/iw\,$h/ih))/2" -c:v libx264 -crf 22 -preset slow -pix_fmt yuv420p -c:a aac -q:a 1 -ac 2 -ar 44100 ${f%mp4}mkv;done`

Some of my input videos didn't have an audio channel, so I used a command like this to add a silent audio channel to the videos:

`for f in *.mkv;do ffprobe $f|&grep -q 1:\ Audio||{ ffmpeg -i $f -f lavfi -i anullsrc -c:a aac -shortest -c:v copy temp-$f;mv temp-$f $f;};done`

I then concatenated the videos using `mkvmerge`:

```
mkvmerge -o output.mkv `printf %s\\n *.mkv|sed '1!s/^/+ /'`
```

Comment: OP asks about ffmpeg. What's the point to offer other tool? Like you ask something about C# and someone answers about qBasic...

Comment: After spending hours trying every FFmpeg suggestion/fix i could fine i gave up and tired this. It worked first time. Thanks a lot i wish i had tired it first.