# How to Bulk Add Outro with ffmpeg?

Tags: batch-file, video, ffmpeg

I've got an script which is to bulk join and intro file, video files and a outro into one file:

```
cd converted
    for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
      echo.>%%f.list
      echo file 'intro_outro/c_intro.mp4' >> %%f.list
      echo file '%%f' >> %%f.list
      echo file 'intro_outro/c_outro.mp4' >> %%f.list
    )


for %%f in (*.list) do (
  ffmpeg -f concat -i %%f -c copy concatenated/%%f.mp4
)
```

Now I have a problem, I just got a video file and an outro file and I don't need an intro.
What do I need to change to just add an outro to the videos in bulk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the intro reference, so

```
cd converted
    for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
      echo.>%%f.list
      echo file '%%f' >> %%f.list
      echo file 'intro_outro/c_outro.mp4' >> %%f.list
    )


for %%f in (*.list) do (
  ffmpeg -f concat -i %%f -c copy concatenated/%%f.mp4
)
```

Comment: Okay I used this code now.

My first mp4 file is: 15 seconds long
My Second mp4 file (outro) is: 3 seconds long

and the concated video is suddenly 20 seconds long and the sound of the outro starts 1-2 seconds to late

Any idea how i could fix this ?

Comment: I found another answer from you which is maybe the fix for my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35520705/2059411  <-- can we integrate this code into the code above, so bulk adding outro will work perfectly ?

Comment: Let me see the input properties for a pair of main file and outro.

Comment: Here I just uploaded the codes/bat files which i am using and the outro file and a sample mp4 file. Then you can fully understand how I do it. Maybe I did a mistake somewhere. https://www.dropbox.com/s/0fxz8jaqyu59tdn/ffmpeg_convert_concat_batch.rar?dl=0

Comment: For concat, the streams should have the same properties. But your video frame rates don't match, neither do your audio sampling rates. Also, your main audio is 0.8 seconds longer than the video, so the joint occurs later compared to the video joint. You can try to correct that by running `ffmpeg -i main -c copy -shortest output.mp4` for each main video.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correctly. I assume you have downloaded the files first i run the convert.bat, so the videos get converted to the same file ending in this case .mp4 then I run the concat.bat which should concat the two video files. Do i need to run this on the concated file or do i need to do that on the source file already ? And how can I do that it bulk, it would take really long to do it for over 1000 videos

Comment: Like this? 
    for %%f in (*.mp4) do (
 ffmpeg -i "%%f" -c copy -shortest %%f.mp4
    )

Comment: Yes, like that. The concat demuxer in copy mode only works correctly for files with same properties and streams within a file of equal length.

Comment: So if it is needed to  be done before I convert the files then this should be the right code for the convert.bat: http://pastebin.com/ViEdR1Sd right ?

Comment: Since you are re-encoding, you can skip the first command and add `shortest` to the 2nd.

Comment: Ok, I did all of this now and still the outcome is not working correctly see here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3vsf6a9ps3hkfs6/c_976854978987732152_1772817218.mp4.list_x264.mp4?dl=0
The sound of the outro starts to late how can i fix this ?

Comment: The conversion commands as well. You did insert the shortest in the 2nd command from the earlier pastebin?

Comment: Add the same sampling rate in both conversions e.g. `-ar 44100`